# Apache Virtual Host in CGI mode

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I changed my Apache configuration to run under FastCGI and now if I check phpinfo() details I see: Server API = CGI/FastCGI

The Apache is listening on port 8090

Then I moved to modify accordingly my virtual hosts files

extra/httpd-vhosts.conf (this is a piece of the file):

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    ServerName profonderia.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/EPLC/Shared/progetti/LIVE-SOURCES/profonderia"
    <Directory "C:/EPLC/Shared/progetti/LIVE-SOURCES/profonderia">
        Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    ServerName lg_ci3.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/EPLC/Shared/progetti/LIVE-SOURCES/lg_CI3"
    <Directory "C:/EPLC/Shared/progetti/LIVE-SOURCES/lg_CI3">
        Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my windows hosts file I have :

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1      profonderia.local
    127.0.0.1      lg_ci3.local
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Some day ago my Apache was not working under FastCGI and my extra/httpd-vhosts.conf was the same without "Options ExecCGI" line.... and all was working fine;
Now after the changes the strange thing is that if I call http://profonderia.local:8090/ it works fine, instead if I call http://lg_ci3.local:8090/ it fails with error 403..You have no permission....

I checked on-line but I found nothing to understand why the two virtual hosts are not working the same.

Comment: Maybe a simple file permission error? http status 403 can also be cause by that, not only by ht http host options.

Comment: I'm under xampp on a windows 7 machine; the two directories have no particular permission and before to switch to FastCGI the 2 virtual hosts were working fine.... this is the reason I think the problem is connected to the new configuration

Comment: Maybe a caching issue? Try a deep reload in your browser or, even better, clear your browsers cache.

Comment: I cleared cache and also tried on another browser, but I have always the same problem

Comment: OK, then check the configuration again: restart the http daemon once, make a single request that leads to status 403 and check what entries have been added to the http servers error log file. Anything of interest, typically you should get a reason for the denial.

Comment: thanks @arkascha, it was a problem due to .htaccess configuration.

Now I finally solved it

Comment: Why on earth do you use `.htaccess` style files if you have access to and control over the real configuration of the http server? That makes little sense except in very, very special situations... Those `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow the http server down. They are only implemented for users that do _not_ have access to the server configuration. So for users of cheap hosting service providers for example.

Comment: it was there probably for error and it simply contains rules for url rewriting so I disabled it